# How to implement a read only controller action

Tags: grails, grails-orm, domain-object

I have an `Order` domain class (`hasMany = [items: Item]`) and an edit screen which lets you edit an instance of `Order`.

The edit screen has the `totalCost` field which is calculated via ajax as `items` are added/removed. The backend calculation of `totalCost` is complex one (cannot be done on the front end, has to be on the back end) and it depends on:

- the state of the unsaved changes on the edit screen
- properties of the `order` being edited which are not on the edit screen itself

So, to carry out the `totalCost` calculation, I do something like this:

```
def ajaxCalculateTotalCost() {
    def order = Order.get(params.id)
    order.properties = params
    def totalCost = // complex calculation based on params.items, logged in user and so on...
    // return totalCost as JSON here
}
```

The problem with this is that once the ajax call is made to `ajaxCalculateTotalCost()` the `Order` instance being edited gets saved. As far as I understand, Spring or Hibernate flushes the session at the end of the HTTP request???

This is a problem as if the user has added/removed `items` the cannot cancel their changed by clicking `Cancel` at the bottom of the form (the `Order` got saved when the ajax call happened).

Can anyone suggest how to carry out the calculation without saving the `Order` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `read` instead of `get`.

```
def order = Order.read(params.id)
```

and mark the controller action as `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`.

Another option is to move the calculation into a `service class` and mark the service method `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`

Answer (score 0):

Do what @saw303 says or do `order.discard()` to tell Hibernate to not persist that object